# Using jQuery to add scrolling to a flat UL list

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollview

I have this UL list:

```
<ul class="third-level-nav">
  <li><a href="/accommodations/Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/accommodations/Household-Ordering-Tutorial.aspx">
       Household Ordering Tutorial
      </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/accommodations/List-of-standard-items.aspx">
       List of standard items
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="/accommodations/Costs-of-utilities.aspx">
      Costs of utilities
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It displays like this on the page, as a flat list (LI floated left, list-style:none):

`Home |  Household Ordering Tutorial  |  List of standard items  |  Costs of utilities`

The problem is, there could be a dozen or more of these LI items, and they'll wrap to the next line. Is there a way to use jQuery to make the list scrollable? In other words, it would show a `>` if there are more items, and a `<` when the user has scrolled some items out of view? It would smoothly scroll left and right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without jQuery or JavaScript. Try this CSS instead of using `float`:

```
LI {
    display:inline-block; 
    list-style:none;
}
UL {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/HhecV/

This won't make the list scrollable, but it will make the entire page scrollable. To make just the list scroll horizontally, add `overflow:auto`:

```
LI {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
UL {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/HhecV/2/

Comment: Thanks, mblase75. As great as your answer is, I'm still looking for a cool jQuery solution without the scrollbars that come with a scrolling element. I'd like to have some arrows that let the user click to move through elements.

Comment: I'd like to implement a sliding technique something similar to this for the LI elements: http://codecanyon.net/item/sliding-tabs-jquery-plugin/141774