# Add scrolling to horizontal UL list with Next/Previous buttons

Tags: jquery, html-lists, horizontal-scrolling

I want to add next/previous buttons to my horizontal scrolling list. I have followed this post: [Using jQuery to add scrolling to a flat UL list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715356/using-jquery-to-add-scrolling-to-a-flat-ul-list)

But it didn't work for me, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PrasadJadhav/45zyu/3/

I tried using:

```
ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I don't want scroll-bar to appear for the full list by using:

```
overflow : scroll;
/* OR */
overflow : auto;
```

Is there any Jquery plugin which can solve this problem?

**Update:**
can we do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2Hr4U/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using this plugin:  [Smooth Div Scroll.](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/)

Check this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PrasadJadhav/2Hr4U/804/

I used following code:

```
$("div.tabmenu").smoothDivScroll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting like

http://jsfiddle.net/45zyu/4/

```
.tabmenu {position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 0px; width:500px;height:30px; border:1px olid green; white-space: nowrap; height: 50%; overflow: auto; }

.tabmenu ul {list-style: none;  white-space: nowrap; margin:0px;  display: inline-block;}

.tabmenu ul li { display: inline-block; float: left; position: relative; background: #4b6592 }
.tabmenu ul li a { display: inline-block; color: #fff; }

.tabmenu ul li a span { display: block; padding: 9px 15px 9px 10px;  font-size: 10px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you just want a custom scrollbar in form of small plugin that you can style, I would recommend this one: http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/